# How to access the name of a ref object from a array in Vue.js 3 / Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Form, with some  fields.
Get there value with v-model to some ref objects.
To get my data in my FormData object, I need the name and the value of the ref objects..
I don't want formData.append() to repeat

I can't get the name of the ref objects. Is this possible?

- put the objects in an array.
- iterate trough the array (foreach) and append the data to my FormData object.

"formdata.append("nameOfRefObject", refObject.value)"

I've tryed

```
formData.append(Object.keys(key)[0], key.value);
```

[image: the "name" I've got is __v_isShallow and I can't find any name in this object to access]

Here is the Code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const surname = ref("");
const name = ref("");
const company = ref("");
const phone = ref("");
const email = ref("");
const msg = ref("");

async function submitForm(submit: Event) {
  
  const helperArr = [surname, name, company, phone, email, msg, token];
  const formData = new FormData();
  helperArr.forEach((key) => {
    formData.append(Object.keys(key)[0], key.value);
  });
await axios.post(apiEndpoint, formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use forms you can use the `reactive()` function, something like this:

```
const form = reactive({
    surname: "",
    name: "",
    company: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
    msg: "",
});
```

And you don't need to create a `FormData()` instance. You can pass directly the reactive form to the ep, something like this:

```
const response = await axios.post(apiEndpoint, form, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
});

console.log(response)
```

If you want the v-model support for `reactive()` function, it's as simple as doing this in your input:

```
<input v-model="form.name" />
```

***Extra comments***

If you want type the object, you can do this:

```
const form = reactive<Interface>({
    surname: "",
    name: "",
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used your solution. I guess you cant access the like I tryed to do.